# R Shiny app embedded with iframe - load speed

Tags: php, r, iframe, shiny

We have two Shiny apps embedded in an iframe container. Accessing the shiny apps directly loads instantly, whereas the embedded version takes 6 seconds.

The iframe is called [as follows](https://github.com/ilri/feast-data-web/blob/master/templates/Download/index.php):

```
<div class="col-md-12 iframe-container">
      <iframe  frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="<?php echo $currentEntity['shiny_download']; ?>" ></iframe>
</div>
```

What can we do to improve this load time?

Note: professional developers worked on the PHP side of this, so I won't be able to answer questions like: why `php echo $currentEntity`?